# How does link_to decides which action invoke in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following the tutorial at rubyonrails.org (I assume it's about rails 4)

In this line:
`<%= link_to "My Blog", controller: "posts" %>`

how does rails decide which action invoke from posts_controller?

Is it equivalent to this?
`<%= link_to 'My Blog', posts_path %>`

And if so, when to use which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, both will yield the same `<a>` tag with an `href` attribute of `/posts`.

`<%= link_to 'My Blog', posts_path %>` is a resourceful route that follows RESTful conventions as defined by Rails. `posts_path` is a route to the `index` action of `posts_controller.rb`. This path is very likely defined by a declaration of a resource route for `posts`:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :posts

# rake db:migrate
              posts GET    /posts(.:format)                        posts#index
                    POST   /posts(.:format)                        posts#create
           new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                    posts#new
          edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)               posts#edit
               post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                    posts#show
                    PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                    posts#update
                    DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                    posts#destroy
```

In contrast, `<%= link_to "My Blog", controller: "posts" %>` does not utilize a named route, but rather, passes arguments that specifically route to a controller. Because no `action` is passed, the link helper builds a route to the default action – the `index` action. Given this pattern of routing, the following list approximates the named resource routes from above:

```
<%= link_to 'My Blog', controller: 'posts' %> # /posts
<%= link_to 'My Blog', controller: 'posts', action: 'new' %> # /posts/new
<%= link_to 'My Blog', controller: 'posts', action: 'edit', id: post_id %> # /posts/post_id/edit
<%= link_to 'My Blog', controller: 'posts', action: 'show', id: post_id %> # /posts/post_id
```

**Which method is preferred?**

Between the two choices, it is preferred to use the named `posts_path` route. By using named routes, you keep your code DRY and circumvent issues related to links breaking when routes change, and vice-versa. Moreover, named routes help ensure that URLs are well-formed and links utilize correct HTTP request methods.

Answer (score 3):

Both `<%= link_to "My Blog", controller: "posts" %>` and `<%= link_to 'My Blog', posts_path %>` are equivalent, producing: `<a href="/posts">My Blog</a>`.

That said, the second one, `<%= link_to 'My Blog', posts_path %>`, is the preferred method as it is resource orientated. Please see the examples section of the [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) documentation.

The first example, `<%= link_to "My Blog", controller: "posts" %>`, is a much older style of arguments, but it can prove useful when combined with the action if you have non-standard actions mapped to custom url's.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the router defaults to the `index` action when no action is explicitly provided.

So yes, in this case, these two are equivalent:

```
link_to 'My Blog', controller: 'posts'
link_to 'My Blog', posts_path
```